# How to pass the date into GregorianCalendar in JAVA?

Tags: java, datetime

Sorry, I am very new to this.

```
this is from another class
private String name;
private String code;
private GregorianCalendar startDateTime;
private GregorianCalendar endDateTime;
```

---

```
this is for main
CourseDetail []c1={new course("Java","AACS 2083",
new GregorianCalendar(2015,06,20,14,00),new GregorianCalendar(2015,06,21,15,00))};
```

Am I close to the answer?

May I ask how to pass the date into the GregorianCalendar by using method above??
Sorry for this dummy question...

Comment: Side note: consider to use the new Date & Time API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use `util date` to `GregorianCalendar`

```
Date date = new Date();
GregorianCalendar gregoriancalendar = new GregorianCalendar();
gregoriancalendar.setTime(date);
```

Directly set date

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 2015);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 7);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 23);
```

Constructors this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#GregorianCalendar(int,%20int,%20int))

```
public GregorianCalendar(int year,
                 int month,
                 int dayOfMonth)


public GregorianCalendar(int year,
                 int month,
                 int dayOfMonth,
                 int hourOfDay,
                 int minute)
```

Example

```
GregorianCalendar calendar=new GregorianCalendar(2015, 6, 23,23, 12);
```

Comment: there are several constructors. But your one also right.?

Comment: thx, I really appreciate your passion in answering my question, sry to you that I am still new to this. 
I trying create the object and pass in data in the same time, so may I pass in the date too? The constructor already declared in other class

Comment: @Exbury the month value in the constructor is zero based for some reason, so GregorianCalendar(2015, 6, 23) for the equivalent of gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 2015);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 7);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 23);

Answer (score 0):

You create a new object of GregorianCalendar and then set the date:

```
GregorianCalendar gc = new GregorianCalendar();
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 2015);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.MONTH, 4);
gc.set(GregorianCalendar.DATE, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  CourseDetail []c1={new Course("Java","AACS 2083",new GregorianCalendar(2015,06,20,14,00),new GregorianCalendar(2015,06,21,15,00))};
```

oh, finally, I just know that I can pass the date in this form. Thx everyone !!